# Pictures from photo stream back to camera roll?

Tags: iphone, photo-stream

I recently had my iPhone wiped from keyboard issues so my pictures were backed up with the iCloud in photo stream. How do I place those photo stream pictures back to my camera roll? I've tried to select all my photo stream an move it to the camera roll folder but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can it save to the Camera Roll with the Arrow in the left corner and choose "Save to Camera Roll". It's the last Menu Point.

Comment: Left corner of when I'm in my photos or once taking a picture? I'm not seeing that save to camera roll option

Comment: Hum, I have checked it again and goes on my iPhone to the Photostream, select a picture, tapped the left corner and choose "Sichern zu Aufnahmen/Save to Cameraroll". Are you sure that you have select a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Go to photo stream, there is an arrow in the RIGHT corner (not left). Touch the arrow and it will come to a screen that says select photos, touch a photo it will have a check mark on it then in lower right corner touch save and it will appear in your camera roll. I am just learning myself, I hope the helps.